# Do the jobs after a PhD in Statistics require a minimum of 3-4 years previous work experiences in the industries?

Tags: phd, career-path, statistics

I am a full-time student (29) in M.Sc Statistics which is about to finish. I have a less-than-one year job experience. I intend to go for Ph.D in Statistics and I have seen many industries want a minimum 3 or 4 years work experience for Ph.D Statistics level jobs. I need to know that if this work experience is mandatory. Also, kindly let me know if one can 'begin' a full-time work experience after getting a Ph.D in Statistics.

Thank you in advance and your kind reply is highly appreciated.

Comment: This totally depends on the company if this is mandatory or not. How should we know?

Comment: Unless your statistics program is very applied it will prepare you to do research. That changes the situation a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior experience is a two edged sword. On the one hand, you probably learn to do some things useful for a particular industry. On the other hand, you may be saddled with non-disclosure and non-compete agreements.

If you want a life of research (as opposed to application) then you probably want a PhD and an academic career. But a doctorate may not be well suited to a life in the commercial world other than in a few places. But those places also probably require quite a lot of knowledge about some application area (finance, say).

But, the question may be moot for you. If you don't have the experience, then you just don't. Full stop. You can try to get it, of course, but before you do anything like taking time off or going for the doctorate, first look at what life would be like under various scenarios.

I would guess that some companies want a lot of experience. I would guess that others want none at all. If you are asking about the situation in a particular place, then explore it there, by talking with companies that you might want to work at.

You have to get on *some* path now, but you don't need to make immediate life changing decisions immediately. Keep flexible and look at the options as they open.

Comment: Sound advice. I would add only that many employers don't really know what they want other than some crude filter to whittle down the number of candidates they have to interview. Sometimes, you can avoid being filtered out if you can find a way of showing the potential employer that you have uniquely relevant skills. To do that you must do your homework on that employer.